# How to revert file to pre-cloned state

Tags: android, git, android-studio, terminal

I am working on a project. There is one file I changed by accident. I would like to revert it to its pre-cloned state. And yes, I already did a number of merges. How do I do that?

Comment: By "merges" do you mean "commits"? Please show a mock version of your current repository state, including history of commits made.

Comment: yes I mean commits and pushes

Comment: The answer to your question depends entirely on how you committed the changes and what other files changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in Android Studio, press alt + 9 to open the Version Control panel. Switch to the Log tab and right click on a previous commit. Select Checkout Revision.